# Global returns to scale

Tags: microeconomics, production-function, producer-theory

I have a production function of the form $f(x_1,x_2) = x_1^a x_2^b$ and I am trying to figure out what the global returns to scale would be given that $a,b \in (0,1)$.

This production function is homogenous of degree $a+b$ so if both $a$ and $b$ are decimals then we could have:

- $(a,b,a+b) = (0.6, 0.7, 1.3)$ (increasing returns)
- $(a,b,a+b) = (0.2, 0.5, 0.7)$ (decreasing returns)
- $(a,b,a+b) = (0.45, 0.55, 1)$ (constant returns)

This would make it difficult to determine exactly what the returns to scale are. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Does [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Returns_to_scale#Formal_definitions) help you?

Comment: Thanks for the edit!

Comment: Using $f(\lambda x_1, \lambda x_2) = \lambda^{a+b} f(x_1, x_2) \gtreqqless \lambda f(x_1, x_2)$ $(\forall \ \lambda > 1)$ and the "formal definition" written on the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Returns_to_scale#Formal_definitions), are you able to solve the question? Hint: It depends on the value of $a+b$.